# OData Web API REST GET how to return 204 or 404 using ODataController

Tags: .net, odata

all!

I am using OData v4, Web API 2.2, and an ODataController class. I have implemented the simple Get methods to return a single row and a set of rows. Everything works great when there are rows to be found. But if I change the $filter or specify a key id that does not exist, my application receives status code 500.

Questions:

1. Should my REST service return 204 or 404? Seems like 500 is bogus.
2. I have seen examples using EntitySetController. But it seems like the latest OData is using System.Web.OData.* where the EntitySetController example is using System.Web.Http.OData.* - is the latter no longer in use? Should I not use EntitySetController?
3. What is the best way for me to modify my OData service to return the appropriate status code?

Here is my controller.

```
using ERSHubRest.Models;

using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Routing;
using System.Web.OData.Query;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ERSHubRest.Controllers
{
    public class AppVersionsController : ODataController
    {
        HubModel db = new HubModel();

        private bool AppVersionsExists(System.Guid key)
        {
             return db.AppVersions.Any( p => p.BusinessId == key );
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<AppVersions> Get()
        {
            if (db.AppVersions.Count() <= 0)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return db.AppVersions;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<AppVersions> Get([FromODataUri] System.Guid key)
        {
            IQueryable<AppVersions> result = db.AppVersions.Where( p => p.BusinessId == key );

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Pete

Answer (score 2):

Use `IHttpActionResult` as the return type, and then return `Ok(object(s))` or `NotFound()` if there weren't any

OData v3: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/

OData v4: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/

Make sure to read through the latest features for each. BreezeJs (and other javascript libraries) aren't updated for v4 yet so you'll need to use v3.

v3 doesn't have features like AttributeRouting and other newer stuff so you might want to read up on their differences.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Thanks, John. I will try it now. The issue of System.Web.OData vs. System.Web.Http.OData was resolved by using the NuGet to update the libraries. All of the references are now to System.Web.Http.OData.*

Comment: Watch out, there are two sets of nuget packages. One for v3 and one for v4 (v5?). There is very little support for javascript for v4+ so if you want to use BreezeJs or others I'd recommend sticking with the v3. v3 does have the EntitySetController while its gone with v4. v4 supports AttributeRouting and other stuff that v3 does not... so make sure to figure out what features you need to see if you need to go with v3 or the latest v4(5?)

Comment: @Pete I updated my answer with more info on v3 vs v4 :)

Comment: Thansk! I am going crazy trying to get this stuff straightened out. Seems like it should be easier than this! I am sticking with v4 but it seems like it always hurts trying to use the latest and greatest.

Comment: @Pete I completely agree... We ended up not going with OData and just using regular ApiControllers since it ended up being a huge headache :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing `result` to `null`, simply return the SingleResult:

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<AppVersions> Get([FromODataUri] System.Guid key)
{
    IQueryable<AppVersions> result = db.AppVersions.Where( p => p.BusinessId == key );

    return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

.NET will take care of the 404 result for you. You can't compare the result of the Where clause to `null` because an `IQueryable` doesn't work that way. It will never be null. You'd have to do `result.SingleOrDefault()` for that to work, but then you'd lose the `IQueryable` for the `OData` functionality.

Not sure why you're getting the 500 error. Maybe using `Count` explicitly (which, again, is unnecessary) messes up the `IQueryable` by putting it into an awkward state, but that only accounts for the `key`-less `GET`.